# Thread-safe random number generator with openMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, openmp, generator

The following simple script produce random number in parallel

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Three integers are expected from the command line.
  // The first integer is a random seed
  // The second integer is the number of threads.
  // The third integer indicates the number of random numbers to produce

  // Read the seed and create the random number generator and the random distribution
  int seed = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  std::mt19937 mt(seed);
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float>  dist(0, 100);

  // Read the number of threads and set it.
  int nbThreads = std::stoi(argv[2]);
  omp_set_num_threads(nbThreads);

  // Number of random number for demonstration
  int n = std::stoi(argv[3]);

  // Will store the random number to print them conveniently
  std::vector<float> store(n);

  // produce 'n' random numbers
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
  {
    store[i] = dist(mt);
  }

  // print the random numbers
  for ( auto& rnd : store )
  {
    std::cout << rnd << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The above script is deterministic when using a single thread

```
./test 3 1 2
55.0798
7.07249

./test 3 1 2
55.0798
7.07249

./test 7 1 2
7.63083
22.7339


./test 7 1 2
7.63083
22.7339
```

However, it is partially stochastic and contain correlation between threads (which can be a pretty big issue) when using more than one thread

```
./test 3 2 2
43.1925
43.1925

./test 3 2 2
55.0798
7.07249

 ./test 7 2 2
22.7339
7.63083

./test 7 2 2
7.63083
7.63083
```

I understand why my code is not thread-safe but I fail to understand how to make it thread-safe. Is it possible to **have deterministic output regardless of the number of threads?**

The goal is that `./test 87 1 200` yield the same output as `./test 87 3 200` (that is the number of threads won't affect the object `store`). If this is not possible, then the goal is that `./test 87 3 200` yield the same output as `./test 87 3 200`.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you want to do? Clearly, a PRNG that produces a sequence of outputs can only produce those outputs in sequence. What do you want?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I edited the post hoping to make it more clear. I am trying to make a deterministic process that takes a random seed and produce random number in a multithreaded fashion. Is it possible? I am not sure my comment just helped you to understand. Can you please be more specific about what is unclear?

Comment: What are the threads going to be doing exactly? For the result to be deterministic, there must be a first result that goes to some particular place. And then, and only then, there can be a second result. Right? It seems you are asking both to do things in a precise sequence (one, then the next, and so on) but also to do them in a multithreaded fashion.

Comment: You can only get deterministic output **per thread**. This is because you cannot guarantee the sequence in which each thread generates random numbers. Obviously a shared PRNG will give you a deterministic sequence of numbers (provided you 'sabotage' your threading a bit to make it thread-safe); but since which thread gets which number is not deterministic, any derivations from the the random numbers are also not deterministic. _Your only reasonable option is to use a separate PRNG instance per thread_.

Comment: @CraigYoung Ok, so it si not possible to ensure that `./test 87 1 200` give the same output as `./test 87 3 200` but it is possible to ensure that `./test 87 3 200` give systematically the same output if we define a PRNG seeded from a value of the main PRNG for each thread. Rest to investigate if this is possible with openMP. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are sharing the state in the `std::mt19937` mt object with each thread, which is not thread-safe.

Either wrap the access of that object with locking of some sort, or provide a separate instance for each thread [EDIT] seeded differently (maybe from the first instance of mt19937 you create) so that each instance gives different results [/EDIT] (if any of that's possible using omp).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Locking is possible with openMP (as one can read [here](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#Locks)) but I don't really understand what it means. Also, can you please be more specific when you say "provide a separate instance"? If I just copy, `mt`, then each thread will produce the exact same output. This would be different from what a single threaded process would produce and it would cause repeated values in `store` which is not desirable. Can you please expand a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Providing two different mt19937 instances (one for each thread, seeded differently) is not the best way of doing this. There is a library dedicated for RNGs in a threaded environment, which you can find [here](https://numbercrunch.de/trng/). Make sure you read the documentation, it is very well written, esp section 2.2.

Comment: Could you summarize **why** thread-local RNG instances are not the best way of doing this how to do it better conceptional? The library link is great, and I'm sure so is the documentation, but it is important to have this also in the answer.